# Debug problematic TP-Link Access Point that is intermittently dropping wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a problem with my TP-Link wifi access point intermittently dropping connections. Turning it off and on again fixes it (doesn't it always?).

What tools can I use (happy to use Windows or Mac) to either trace the dropped connection, and/or debug the reconnection failures?

I can't work out if there's a pattern with the behaviour of some other device on the network, though I can't discount that. If there's some way to prove it one way or the other, that would be great.

I don't mind buying better kit, though I am trying to avoid spending hundreds of £s on Ubiquiti or whatever.

Comment: You can use a packet sniffer looking for dropped packets.  Best approach (I think) is to upgrade the firmware, hard reset to factory specs and set up the wireless again. Test with several wireless devices.

Comment: I've heard negative things about reliability from TP-Link and D-Link.  That is why, even though they can be 40% of the price of other brands, I tend to gravitate towards other brands.  With TP-Link, many of them completely fail in an instant, while many fail until being power cycled and then later completely fail.  If you have hardware going bad, I would suggest consider investing in a better experience.  I know that isn't always an easy pill to swallow, and for that I'm sorry.  Yet to combat failure-related stress, I feel obligated to report my understanding.

Comment: I had these symptoms with an old LinkSys WRT. I ended up replacing it due to incipient hardware failure. How old is your TP-Link?

Answer (score 0):

If a relatively cheap device (e.g., a TP-Link router, unlike an expensive full-fledged server) is routinely acting more reliably after being power-cycled, then replacing the device is probably a good idea.

That doesn't necessarily mean the replacement has to be permanent.  However, using some obtained stock-on-hand is a standard troubleshooting step.  (You asked about tools, and troubleshooting procedures can be considered tools.)

If a replacement device works better, that suggests there is some issue with this device (whether it be caused by software configuration or hardware), so investigating other devices is less likely to be very fruitful.

If the problem's cause is indeed hardware failure, then software-based approaches (running network software on other devices, or even using built-in tools on a device's web interface or SSH command prompt) might not be able to detect the problem well enough to accurately report a precise cause.